# Laravel select query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I a building a query for the below select statement

```
SELECT empname, COUNT(empstatus) 
FROM empattens 
WHERE empstatus='Present' 
  AND id=1;
```

The code which I used is the below one

```
Empatten::where('id', $id)
        ->where('empstatus', '=', 'Present')
        ->get()
        ->count('empstatus');
```

I am receiving only the `count(empstatus)`, but I need the `empname` also,

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `select()` method to specify which fields you would like to select, then combine that with `DB::raw()` to select your `COUNT()`.

```php
Empatten::select('empname', \DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS count"))
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('empstatus', '=', 'Present')
        ->get();
```

But this is not necessarily a valid SQL, since you are using aggregate functions (in this case, `COUNT()`, but other examples are `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`) while selecting columns. You should specify a `GROUP BY` for the columns in the select list which are not part of an aggregate statement. We can do that by using the `groupBy()` method - the result should not change, since you're looking for a specific ID.

```php
Empatten::select('empname', \DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS count"))
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->where('empstatus', '=', 'Present')
        ->groupBy('empname')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$empatten = Empatten::whereId($id)->where('empstatus','Present')->get(['empname']);
```

With this you will get collection as a result then you may get count with

```
$count = $empatten->count();
```

or you may use query like as bellow

```
Empatten::select('empname', \DB::raw("COUNT(*) AS count"))
    ->whereId($id)->where('empstatus','Present')->get();
```